# What should be the relationship between an adminstrators table and users table

Tags: postgresql

If admin account can create user accounts, does this mean that the relationship between the admin table and the users table is:

> ADMIN OneToMany Users

For example, in my project:
[image]

A person with the privilege **adminstrateur** account, can create accounts with the privilege **technicien_sav**. Obviously, each kind of **privilege** grants the one who has it access to different parts of the app.
However, I do not see the SQL relationship necessary for the overall functioning of my app. I.e: The **administrateur** can create **technicien_sav** accounts even without the existence of the relationship between the two.
What do you think?
**PS:** It's been years since I've worked with SQL databases, I hope the question is not too naive.

Comment: Please consider the advice in [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530) concerning the posting of images here. p.s. welcome to the forum!

Comment: If your queries don't look exceptionally complicated then its probably ok.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name porstgres

Comment: @danblack what's okay exactly, I've mentioned several things :p

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell from your image (please post ddl instead), there is no relationship between adminstrateur and technicien_sav. If you add an attribute created_by or administered_by in technicien_sav, there would be a relationship.  Since this attribute most likely is not part of the key for tech... , it would be referred to as a non-identifying relationship. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE adminstrateur
( adminstrateur_id ... not null primary key
, fullname ...
, ...
);

CREATE TABLE technicien_sav
( technicien_sav_id ... not null primary key
, ...
, adminstrateur_id ... not null
      references adminstrateur (adminstrateur_id)
);
```

I prefer using the same attribute name throughout the model, names like id, name, etc are IMO to vague. Even better is to use names from the domain of discourse, but I have no idea what the might be in your case.

Comment: I have been advised on stackoverflow to create one single entity 'User' which will represent both the technician and the administrateur, and then assign the roles accordingly